# Changing filename color in Windows Explorer list view.

Tags: windows, mfc, windows-explorer, subclassing, api-hook

I would like to customize Windows Explorer.

One thing I want to do is changing file name's color in list view if the file has a special condition.
Is it possible by window subclassing? or does it need api hooking?
Please let me know what is the best way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with the window subclassing:

Add NM_CUSTOMDRAW handler to your CListCtrl-derived class

```
void CMyList::OnCustomDraw(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{

LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW lplvcd = (LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW)pNMHDR;

switch (lplvcd->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
{
case CDDS_PREPAINT:
    *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
    break;

case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
    *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;
    break;

case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT | CDDS_SUBITEM:
    lplvcd->clrText = **MY_COLOR**;
    *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;
}
```

}

Comment: And how does this affect Windows Explorer?